# Why iphone doesn't adjust with media queries properly?

Tags: html, css, iphone, sass, media-queries

When I've checked it with chrome inspector with iphone resolution and android devices everything looks great but when I open it with the iphone device it looks overflowed.
Can anyone help me?

link to the site:
https://pre-entrega3-roque-lucas-nesmanpro.vercel.app

link to the repository:
https://github.com/nesmanpro/PFRoqueLucas

i've changed resolutions, added specific size for that ratio aspect and width and height, deleted cache, changed meta tags.
Does any have any different suggestion or solution?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.